# Non-linear ODEs and methods

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, soft-question, numerical-methods

I'm doing an applied maths course on non-linear ODEs which contains a lot of methods, for example, harmonic balance, averaging methods.  My question is, do professional mathematicians generally carry these methods around in their heads or do they know they exist and look up the details when they need them?

Comment: I don't work in this area - I don't work at all because I'm just a student - but I suspect it's both. Probably practice helps you learn a lot of methods, and so you know they exist, but all how they work (kind of) and which kinds of things they're good at doing. Then experience and intuition help you get an idea, which you can then brush up on when you need it.

Comment: Different people do different things. However, I am an amateur mathematician...

Comment: They are elementary, so there is no need to "carry" them around. It is tremendously more difficult, for example, to prepare an equation so that one can apply averaging methods (not to say second order, etc). That's where the mathematician enters. Similar comments apply to all other methods.

Comment: The more you use something, the more likely it is that you will remember it without requiring reference material.